# Wordpress: list authors

Tags: wordpress, themes

I want wordpress to give me an array that contains all authors. There are some dumb functions, that echo html (wp_list_authors()) - but that's not what I want.

I want to get the full profile (ID, name, meta-data).

My current approach isn't, what I am looking for - to be exact, it's **it.

```
$authors = wp_list_authors(array(
'optioncount'   => false, 
'exclude_admin' => false, 
'show_fullname' => false,
'hide_empty'    => false,
'echo'          => false,
'html'      => false)
);
$authors = explode(", ", $authors);
```

And even here I am stuck, since there is no get_author_id_by_name() or similar.

Please help, I don't want to do SQL in a friggin template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is still looking, this is how you return your authors in an array the correct way.

```
function get_all_authors() {
global $wpdb;

foreach ( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT post_author, COUNT(ID) AS count FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND " . get_private_posts_cap_sql( 'post' ) . " GROUP BY post_author") as $row ) :
    $author = get_userdata( $row->post_author );
    $authors[$row->post_author]['name'] = $author->display_name;
    $authors[$row->post_author]['post_count'] = $row->count;
    $authors[$row->post_author]['posts_url'] = get_author_posts_url( $author->ID, $author->user_nicename );
endforeach;

return $authors;
}
```

The returned array (`$authors`) includes the user's ID as the key and also contains author link, post count, and their name. Of course, in your theme's view, you can set `get_all_authors()` to a variable and loop thru it however you'd like.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It blows my mind how wordpress has very few "just give me the data without your stupid formatting, please" type functions.  You think getting a list of authors would be a piece of cake?  BLARG!!!!  Thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you know the user ID, you can use [get_userdata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata).

Otherwise you should take a look at this suggestion:
http://wpengineer.com/list-all-users-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You should better use `get_users`, it's in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users).

Answer (score -1):

```
global $wpdb;
$allAuthorIds = $wpdb->get_column( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->users}" );
$authorsInfo = array();
foreach( $allAuthorIds as $authorId ) {
  $authorsInfo[$authorId] = get_userdata($authorId);
}
```

That will give the info for every single user (including WP extended info) in the $authorsInfo array.  If you need to get users by their role ('author') then you should use the WP_User_Search class.  You're pretty much forced to use SQL here and there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: its not good style imo, but weeell.. anyways ^.^ thanks I'll give it a try

Comment: If anyone uses the above code: make sure to use "$authorId->ID" instead of "$authorId" for get_userdata.